# Express routes not working on production server

Tags: node.js, express

I am struggling to control the flow using a Node Express application on my production server

The home page displays "homepage" but the app.get('/test' gives a "404 - File or directory not found." error

My basic app file for testing on web hosting server
app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
 
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send("test")
}); 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("homepage")
});

app.listen(port);
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `process.env.PORT ||` and leave only 3000 then in theory it should work

Comment: Thank you. This is the error from the server. It runs perfectly on localhost3000. I am looking for guidance for the server error

Comment: Yes Mohammad, the code works perfectly on my local PC. I tested it the home page like myDomain.com and it works. I get the home page message. When I try myDomain.com/test it results in a 404 page not found error. It looks as if the Express Route is not accessed from my web hosting site.